# Determine if a mesh is inside another mesh in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, mesh

I am playing with three JS and want to determine if a mesh is fully inside another mesh. I wrote a little robot which should run into a home box navigated by the player. I know how to detect collision, but is there an easy way to detect if an object is inside another object?

I could calculate center Position of the homebox and compare to robot Position, but maybe there is something build in to threejs.

Comment: Such a thing is not trivial. It depends on what "inside" means, how precise it needs to be, and how irregular the mesh is.

Comment: Inside means the robot should be full in the box so that no part of the robot apears Outside the box. By the way both objects are grounded to zero so in fact they can overlap on the ground.

Comment: You can get a rough approximation by comparing the bounding boxes or even faster the bounding spheres of the objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make a boundingBox (`THREE.Box3`) for both the 'robot' and the 'home' you can use [the `containsBox` method](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Box3.containsBox). So something like this:

```
var robotBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(robot);
var homeBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(home)
```

Where `home` and `robot` are your objects. Now you can do:

```
var robotIsHome = homeBB.containsBox(robotBB);
```

`robotIsHome` will be true if the `robotBB` is completely inside `homeBB`.

Comment: Many thumbs up! Thank you :)

Comment: It is important to note that bounding boxes are axis aligned bounding boxes. Thus if your 'home' and/or 'robot' are not axis aligned it will give wrong result in lot of situations.