# How to detect 3D point is inside the oriented cube or not?

Tags: three.js

I am using THREE.JS, I tried to use THREE.BOX3 methods but it does not work for the oriented box, as it only deals with max and min values. So is there any algorithm to detect 3D point lies inside the Cube volume or not ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221590/determine-if-a-mesh-is-inside-another-mesh-in-threejs this might be you are looking into from code prespective

Answer (score 1):

The `THREE.Box3` class has a `containsPoint` method shown [here in the documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Box3.containsPoint).

You can pass your 3D `point` (of type `THREE.Vector3`) and it will return true/false depending on whether the point is inside or outside the boundaries of the box.

Comment: Thanks,  Earlier I have tried with THREE.BOX3.containsPoint, but it only works with axis oriented cube but if cube got some orientation then box gets bigger as it deals with max and min values of corner points.                                                   In that case even though point is outside actual box, it shows inside.   Is there any other method to do this for non-axis oriented cube?